# .htaccess redirect folder only and not redirect the same folder with variables

Tags: .htaccess, variables, redirect

I'm trying to redirect this

```
www.mydomain.com/womens/badfolder  ->  www.mydomain.com/womens/goodfolder
```

but I do not want to redirect the variables that "badfolder" has.

I would like

```
www.mydomain.com/womens/badfolder?page=variable
```

to stay as is.  Is this possible?

*edit*
Here are my rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=shop.recommend [NC]
RewriteRule . - [F]
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|raw))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

and below that I'll write my redirects.

Comment: Not clear what you mean in last sentence. can you clarify or post your present rules?

Comment: You lost me. You said you want to redirect badfolder to goodfolder but want badfolder to stay as is? what? What is the URL you want to use in the address bar, what is the URL you want to redirect to and then where are the variables you don't want?

Comment: I only want "badfolder" to not redirect if it has variables.  So like "mydomain.com/badfolder" redirects if anyone goes there and if there's a page within it like "mydomain.com/badfolder?page=variable" I do not want that to redirect.  The problem I am having is that anyone who goes to "mydomain.com/badfolder?page=variable" will redirect to "mydomain.com/goodfolder" but I only want that to happen if there is no variable.  Sorry if this is confusing :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule as your **very first rule** in your .htaccess just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(womens)/badfolder$ /$1/goodfolder [L,NC,R]
```